# Swiftmailer not send mail by smtp

Tags: php, email, symfony, smtp, swiftmailer

First I tried send it using `telnet`:

```
$ telnet smtp.yandex.ru 25
Trying 77.88.21.38...
Connected to smtp.yandex.ru.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp12.mail.yandex.net ESMTP (Want to use Yandex.Mail for your domain? Visit http://pdd.yandex.ru)
EHLO yandex.ru
250-smtp12.mail.yandex.net
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 42991616
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-DSN
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
bWFpbEBua3QubWU=
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
*******
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful.
MAIL FROM:mail@nkt.me  
250 2.1.0 <mail@nkt.me> ok
RCPT TO:dev@nkt.me
250 2.1.5 <dev@nkt.me> recipient ok
DATA
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
Subject: Q^BP5Q^AQ^B
To: dev@nkt.me
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued on smtp12.mail.yandex.net as 6VPPHaRoyW-LYnSwHm7
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Closing connection.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

All is ok, I got the mail
Then I setup swiftmailer params:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host:      smtp.yandex.ru
mailer_user:      mail@nkt.me
mailer_password:  *****
mailer_auth_mode:  login
mailer_encryption: ~
mailer_port:       25
```

And create command for send emails:

```
class SendMailCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('mail:send')
            ->setDescription('Send email')
            ->addOption('to', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'Destination email address')
            ->addOption('body', 'b', InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'Mail body')
            ->addOption('subject', 'sub', InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Mail title');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $mailer = $this->getContainer()->get('mailer');
        $to = $input->getOption('to');
        $subject = $input->getOption('subject');
        $body = $input->getOption('body');
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setTo($to)
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setBody($body);
        $output->writeln('To: ' . $to);
        $output->writeln('Subject: ' . $subject);
        $output->writeln('Body: ' . $body);
        $output->writeln('Result: ' . $mailer->send($message));
    }
}
```

And run it:

```
$ app/console mail:send --to="dev@nkt.me" --body="Test body" --subject="Test"
To: dev@nkt.me
Subject: Test
Body: Test body
Result: 1
```

Well, actually not, otherwise I wouldn't have posted the question.
I tried to use ssl, but still not working, what could be the problem?

PS Now i get smtp instead of spool:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $mailer = $this->getContainer()->get('swiftmailer.transport.real');
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setFrom(['mail@nkt.me' => 'Admin'])
        ->setTo($input->getOption('to'))
        ->setSubject($input->getOption('subject'))
        ->setBody($input->getOption('body'));
    $output->writeln(sprintf('Sent %s emails', $mailer->send($message)));
}
```

But also get error:

```
[Swift_TransportException]                                   
Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""
```

Comment: swift's returning true, so it's working fine. You'll have to check mail server logs to see what happened after swift finished handing over the email. e.g. it got dumped as spam by yandex, or by the destination server.

Comment: smtp working with sockets. like i understand all emails push to spool. I set spool-handler to files but mails not send

Comment: no. swiftmailer uses whatever transport method you tell it to. either a local MTA, direct TCP connection to an SMTP server, etc...

Comment: So I choose smtp, so emails should send by smtp

Comment: Probably this helps, but it's hard to say as your question is not really showing that you're on the trouble-shooting train yet: [Got issue with Swift Mailer Not sending messages](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7777968/367456)

Answer (score 0):

I got that same error when I sent directly using the transport instead of passing the transport to a swift mailer instance and then sending.

```
$mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);
$mailer->send($message);
```